# parsing JSON with conditional operators and converting to Elasticsearch language java

Tags: java, json, recursion, elasticsearch

I have JSON with conditional operators like:

```
{
  "or": [
    {
      "and": [
        {
          "ge": [
            "A",
            10
          ]
        },
        {
          "eq": [
            "B",
            20
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "lt": [
        "C",
        30
      ]
    },
    {
      "ne": [
        "D",
        50
      ]
    },
    {
      "and": []
    },
    {
      "or": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to parse the JSON and convert to elasticsearch querying language. But I should be able de-serialize the input JSON first. what is the better way to do it. Using recursive?? If I should use recursive methods what would be the code snippet to build a recursive method.

Comment: Best way is using a JSON parser library. Search and ye shall find.

Answer (score 0):

Well, *deserialization* is transforming data from the wire (filesystem, network, etc), to a data format the program can use, and *parsing* is transforming data from one format to another. Two different things. But I am thinking that parsing is probably what you were referring to.

[How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)